# Normed, Finite Dimensional Vector Space are Complete

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Given a normed, finite-dimensional vector space $V$, where we define the metric $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$. Show that this space, under this metric, is complete - that is, every Cauchy Sequence converges.

I'm looking for, preferably, a linear algebra-based approach if possible. I've already tried writing this in terms of the basis and studying the coefficients. I also looked at the sequence $\| x_n\|$ but I haven't made much connections.

Comment: Do you know that on a finite dimensional vector space all norms are equivalent?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you provide a proof please.